# Capture screen on selected area - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, rectangles, bounds, aforge

A picture box is drawn in my app with size 432*324 and at a location x=100 and y=416. Now I want to capture this exact area/picture box. I have done like below. But screen is capturing in a different location with different size (which is shown in red area on screenshot). Can anyone help me to get rectangle on above specified values?

In short I want exactly capture area with below values :

> width =432,height=324,x=100,y=416

[image]

```
  private void CaptureScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       float screenScaleFactor = objGlobalFns.getScalingFactor();//1.25
        int Width = 432;
        int Height = 324;
        int X = Convert.ToInt32(100 * screenScaleFactor);
        int Y = Convert.ToInt32(416 *  screenScaleFactor);

 //------Code for record screen -----------//

         _Screenwriter.Open(
               fullName,
               Width,
               Height,
               10, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 1000000);
            Rectangle rectBounding = new Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height);
            this._streamVideo = new AForge.Video.ScreenCaptureStream(rectBounding);
         }
```

Comment: You don't need to apply scaleFactor. Just get the location and size of `PictureBox`. Also don't use `this.CreateGraphics()`, instead, move the painting to `Paint` event handle and `Invalidate` the form when needed.

Comment: @TaW  stretchmode

Comment: yup i noticed but it is meaningless since you want to draw onto the form anyway. Do as Reza told you!

Comment: What is that you're actually trying to achive here? If you just want to fill the PictureBox with a colored rectangle, you just need to call `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);` in the Paint event of the PictureBox. Are you instead trying to *hide/select* a specific area of the Image?

Comment: PLEASE check my edited question.